# Scala: How to add a column with the value of a changed field that was changed between two tables

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables with the same schema (A and B) where every unique ID in table A also exists in table B in a 1 to 1 way. I want to add a column to table B with the name of the column whose value is different between the tables for each row. There is only one difference per row.

For example:

### Table A:

```
{ "id1": 1,"id2": "a","name": "bob","state": "nj"}

{"id1": 2,"id2": "b","name": "sue","state": "ma"}
```

### Table B:

```
{"id1": 1,"id2": "a","name": "bob","state": "fl"}

{"id1": 2,"id2": "b","name": "susan","state": "ma"}
```

After comparing them, I want Table B to look like this:

```
{"id1": 1,"id2": "a","name": "bob","state": "fl", "changed_field": "state"}

{"id1": 2,"id2": "b","name": "susan","state": "ma", "changed_field": "name"}
```

I can't find any functions that do this in Spark Scala's data frames. Is there something that I missed?

EDIT: I am working with hundreds to thousands of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the fields in an UDF which generates the appropriate string:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df_a = Seq(
  (1, "a", "bob", "nj"),
  (2, "b", "sue", "ma")
).toDF("id1", "id2", "name", "state")

val df_b = Seq(
  (1, "a", "bob", "fl"),
  (2, "b", "susane", "ma")
).toDF("id1", "id2", "name", "state")

val compareFields = udf((aName:String,aState:String,bName:String,bState:String) => {
  val changedState = if (aState != bState) Some("state") else None
  val changedName = if (aName != bName) Some("name") else None
  Seq(changedName, changedState).flatten.mkString(",")
 }
)


df_b.as("b")
.join(
   df_a.as("a"), Seq("id1", "id2")
)
.withColumn("changed_fields",compareFields($"a.name",$"a.state",$"b.name",$"b.state"))
.select($"id1",$"id2",$"b.name",$"b.state",$"changed_fields")
.show()
```

gives

```
+---+---+------+-----+--------------+
|id1|id2|  name|state|changed_fields|
+---+---+------+-----+--------------+
|  1|  a|   bob|   fl|         state|
|  2|  b|susane|   ma|          name|
+---+---+------+-----+--------------+
```

EDIT:

Here a more generic version which compares all fields at once:

```
val compareFields = udf((a:Row,b:Row) => {
  assert(a.schema==b.schema)
  a.schema
    .indices
    .map(i => if(a.get(i)!=b.get(i)) Some(a.schema(i).name) else None)
    .flatten
    .mkString(",")
}
)


df_b.as("b")
  .join(df_a.as("a"), $"a.id1" === $"b.id1" and $"a.id2" === $"b.id2")
    .withColumn("changed_fields",compareFields(struct($"a.*"),struct($"b.*")))
    .select($"b.id1",$"b.id2",$"b.name",$"b.state",$"changed_fields")
  .show()
```

Comment: @MainKhan No, just `spark.implicits._` (but this was also necessary for the first solution)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to achieve this without having to "spell-out" the columns, and without a UDF (only using built-in functions):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

// list of columns to compare
val comparableColumns = A.columns.tail // without id

// create Column that would result in the name of the first differing column:
val changedFieldCol: Column = comparableColumns.foldLeft(lit("")) {
  case (result, col) => when(
    result === "", when($"A.$col" =!= $"B.$col", lit(col)).otherwise(lit(""))
  ).otherwise(result)
}

// join by id1, add changedFieldCol, and then select only B's columns:
val result = A.as("A").join(B.as("B"), "id1")
  .withColumn("changed_field", changedFieldCol)
  .select("id1", comparableColumns.map(c => s"B.$c") :+ "changed_field": _*)

result.show(false)
// +---+---+-----+-----+-------------+
// |id1|id2|name |state|changed_field|
// +---+---+-----+-----+-------------+
// |1  |a  |bob  |fl   |state        |
// |2  |b  |susan|ma   |name         |
// +---+---+-----+-----+-------------+
```

Comment: Assuming the join is on 2 columns and not one, you might want to define them as `val ids = Seq("id1", "id2")` and then later on `comparableColumns = A.columns.diff(ids)`, `A.as("A").join(B.as("B"), ids)` and also `Seq("id2") ++ comparableColumns.map(c => s"B.$c") :+ "changed_field": _*`